# Cómo crear y renombrar una fila en un dataframe que recoja la media de cada columna (una de las columnas tiene valores NA)

Tags: r, dataframe, rstudio

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en R y tengo un data frame con 50 filas y algunas columnas. Quiero añadir una fila que contenga la media de cada columna, incluido de la ultima columna que contiene valores NA.

El dataframe con el que estoy practicando es este:

```
state.df = as.data.frame(state.x77)
```

Y he probado a hacer esto:

```
apply = apply(state.df, MARGIN = 2, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
rbind(state.df,apply)  
rownames(state.df)[nrow(state.df)] = 'Medias'
```

He usado la función apply para crear una nueva fila que acepte valores NA y que nos calcule la media, luego el rbind para añadir la fila al dataframe y por ultimo he utilizado rownames para renombrar la fila que por defecto tiene el nombre de "51", el problema es que haciendo esto, parece que se borra el último registro y lo sustituye por Medias, aunque tampoco me calcula las medias de las columnas.

Luego probe a hacer esto:

```
rbind(state.df,apply, Medias=colMeans(state.df))
```

En el que directamente en el rbind ya le digo que me calcule las medias de las columnas pero el problema es que me devuelve dos filas nuevas exactamente iguales, una llamada '51' y otra llamada 'Medias'.

Así:

```
West Virginia     1799.00 3617.0       1.40  69.4800  6.700  41.600 100.00  24070.00
Wisconsin         4589.00 4468.0       0.70  72.4800  3.000  54.500 149.00  54464.00
Wyoming            376.00 4566.0       0.60  70.2900  6.900  62.900 173.00  97203.00
51                4246.42 4435.8       1.17  70.8786  7.378  53.108 104.46  70735.88
Medias            4246.42 4435.8       1.17  70.8786  7.378  53.108 104.46  70735.88
```

Quiero eliminar la fila 51.

Hay que tener en cuenta que la ultima columna cuenta con valores NA, por eso creo que no puedo dejar de usar la función apply, para poner el argumento 'na.rm = TRUE'

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que solo me aparezca la fila 'Medias'? ¿Por qué se me crean 2 filas exactamente iguales que únicamente varían en el nombre?

Cualquier ayuda que me déis estaré eternamente agradecido. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

te aparecen dos filas porque estas concatenando 3 cosas
state.df, apply y Medias=colMeans(state.df)

prueba solo concatenando el df original y Medias, ademas colmeans si acepta na.rm = T

```
state.df2 = rbind(state.df,Medias=colMeans(state.df,na.rm = T))
```